# My javascript call is being ignored but why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

To break down what im trying to achieve. As you scroll down to a certain div the animation is called and takes place. The CSS is working fine so it slides in nicely as it should. The js is being ignored no matter where I place it so the trigger happens as the page loads and not when it hits the div.

So here is my code...

```
       <script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#thedevimage').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+1) {
                $(this).addClass("slideRight");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the html...

```
<div class="thedev">

    <div class="left">

<div id="thedevimage" class="slideRight"><img src="images/xcode.png" style="width:100%;" /></div>
</div></div>
```

And the CSS...

```
#thedevimage{
    width: 80%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slideRight{
    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight; 

    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateX(4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateX(-2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    65%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
    }
    95%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2%);
    }           
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('#thedevimage').each(` doesn't make sense. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: How do you mean? I thought it would have to relate to the object no?

Comment: use   $('#thedevimage img')

Comment: It looks like the ID is unique, so it would just iterate over a collection containing a single element. That said, the element already has the `slideRight` class in your HTML, so calling `.addClass('slideRight');` wouldn't do anything.

Comment: By changing the name of that ID changes nothing on the trigger...I am finding this very off - it does animate regardless but not at the point of hitting the class 'thedev' where I want it to

Comment: Your code works, you just already have slideRight class. I am not sure what would you want to accomplish?

Comment: So I have noticed something... it animates right away on page load - then when set to 1 on the topOfWindow it animates as it almost touches the top of the image. Now - I am scratching my head now because I want it to stay hidden until it hits the div

Comment: So may ?i ask exactly what it is that needs changing here - I have been looking at this for way too long my eyes have gone fuzzy. I have changed literally everything...

Comment: @user3328557 Have you deleted `class="slideRight"` from the HTML?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Winner!